# External JS file causes 'Unexpected token <' on one page but not on another

Tags: javascript, runtime-error

Hey so I started getting this error *Unexpected token <* today and I've been trying to locate the error and it seems to come from my main.js file when I'm on the page edit.php. When I'm on dashboard.php it works great with no errors! I've ran the code through multiple JS lint softwares with no luck. I've included a snippet of the code I recently added.

```
function navigateTo(action, path)
{
    var id = $(event.currentTarget).attr('id');
    var f_path = $.parseJSON($("body").data("firebase_path"));

    if(action === 0)
    {
        firebase = firebase.root();
        firebase = firebase.child(f_path);

        firebase.off("child_added", fb_event_added);
        firebase.off("child_changed", fb_event_changed);

        $("#files").empty();
        hideDetails();

        fb_event_added = firebase.orderByPriority().on('child_added', function(push)
        {
            triggerFirebaseEvents("file", "child_added", push);
        });
        fb_event_changed = firebase.orderByPriority().on('child_changed', function(push)
        {
            triggerFirebaseEvents("file", "child_changed", push);
        });
    }
}

function triggerFirebaseEvents(type, event, push)
{
    var key = push.key(), icon_type;
    push = push.val();

    if(type == "file" && event == "child_added")
    {
        $('<div id="' + key + '" class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 file">').append(
            $('<div id="file_' + key + '" class="well well-sm">').html('<p class="mn"><i class="fa ' + icon_type + ' fa-fw text-' + push.color + '"></i> ' + push.name + '</p>')
        ).appendTo('#files');

        $("#file_" + key).data('file-details', JSON.stringify(push));
        UIkit.sortable($(".file"), { });
    }
    else if(type == "file" && event == "child_changed")
    {
        if(push.removed) $("#" + key).addClass("hidden");
        else
        {
            $('#' + key).empty().append(
                $('<div id="file_' + key + '" class="well well-sm">').html('<p class="mn"><i class="fa ' + icon_type + ' fa-fw text-' + push.color + '"></i> ' + push.name + '</p>')
            );
            $("#file_" + key).data('file-details', JSON.stringify(push));
        }
    }
}
```

It's weird that it works on one page but not the other.

**PS.** Could it have something to do with a poorly configured .htaccess maybe? Because on the file it throws the error, there's a htaccess rewrite configured.

Comment: Most commonly this comes when attempting to parse XHR responses assuming they're JSON but your webserver is serving up an HTML error page.

Comment: Checking in the Network tab, shows what exactly happens when you request the file.

Comment: What's the external JS here?

Comment: @PraveenKumar The included JS is from the external JS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because the JavaScript file which you are trying to load has either:

- Unescaped HTML content.
- Loads a 404 or other Error page.

Make sure you give the URLs correctly and handle them too. Checking in the Network tab, shows what exactly happens when you request the URL.

Comment: What should I be looking for in the Network Tab? No failed requests appear and all requests return 200 codes and 304 (Not modifed)...

Comment: @MagnusBurton What's the external URL?

Comment: @MagnusBurton Most common reason is, the browser is trying to access a JavaScript file, instead it encounters a HTML page!

Comment: Do you mind taking a quick look on my test page for yourself? Would really appreciate that

Comment: @MagnusBurton Please... Where's the link, buddy?

Comment: @MagnusBurton Internal Server Error at `http://www.magnusburton.com/dl/assets/signup`.

Comment: I'm so sorry about that, login using magnusburton and Test123

Comment: @MagnusBurton Indeed, your `main.js` is a HTML file: http://i.imgur.com/emCa7az.png?1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91025/discussion-between-praveen-kumar-and-magnus-burton).